# $scope doesnt want to update

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I have problem with updating $scope. I had problem before but $apply makes work everything. Now I don't know what to do. $scope.sensor doesn't update. JSON data is downloaded from server but it doesn't update $scope. Here is my code (updated):

```
app.controller('scheme', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {

$scope.showinfo = function(sensor, $event) {

    var info = document.querySelector("#info");

    if (info.style.opacity == 0) {

            $http.get("http://www.hbmedia.pl/client/zgazowarka/json2.php?module=sensor&code="+code+"&sensor="+sensor).then(function(response) {
                $scope.sensor = response.data;
                $scope.$digest();
                console.log($scope.sensor);
            });

            info.style.top = parseFloat($event.target.style.top.replace(',', '.')) + "%";
            info.style.left = parseFloat($event.target.style.left.replace(',', '.')) + "%";
            info.style.opacity = 1;

    } else {

        info.style.opacity = 0;

    }
}

refresh();
});


<strong>{{ sensor.name }}</strong>
<span>{{ sensor.code }}</span>
<p>{{ sensor.min }}-{{ sensor.max }}</p>
```

Comment: Two things; 1: Is `$scope.sensors` is typo? Do you mean `$scope.sensor` here? and 2: Have you tried using `$apply` after you update `sensor`?

Comment: First of all instead of adding click listeners from js function you can use ng-click

Comment: $scope.sensors is typo. I tried to use $apply after update $scope.sensor.
I will try with ng-click but anyway it should work, am I right?

Comment: Use [`ngClick`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) instead of `addEventListener("click"..`; use services to fetch the data from your server side API; use `controller as` to prevent scope inheritance issues.

Comment: Ok. I've done it with ngClick and it's the same. I get data but $scope doesnt update.